# Colorbar associate with numbers in an array

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I have an array of 155 numbers ranging from 0 to 3. I am wanting have each number correspond to a different colour. So 0-red, 1-blue, 2-green and 3-yellow, then plot the array onto the colorbar

```
origin = 'lower'
#origin = 'upper'

delta = 0.025

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = plt.mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10 * (Z1 - Z2)
levels = salist ##array of 155
CS3 = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels,
                    colors = ('r', 'g', 'b','y'),
                    origin=origin,
                    extend='both')

plt.colorbar(CS3)
```

Comment: Can you take some time to explain your problem in some detail? It's hard to know what you mean. You've also posted a [similar question in the last hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896010/associate-a-colorbar-with-a-matrix-graph) which has gone unanswered presumably because nobody can understand your setup and what your actual question is.

Comment: I just have an array of numbers and want to plot them onto a colorplot

Comment: What is 'onto a colorplot'? Do you have an example of your desired end result?

Comment: John, some of your questions show no work or research on your own. They follow "do this for me" format. This does not match [Stack Overflow purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). It would be easier to help if you can describe your problem better and show what have you tried and why it did not work.